# How to controll textview by Button OnClick in getView method

Tags: android

My App has Listview,Listview Item have one TextView and one Button and other image etc...
and I use the ViewHolder Pattern.

I want to change text in TextView, when the button is clicked

How to control TextView in the Buttons Onclick ?

```
 public class AListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MyData> {

    static class ViewHolder {

        TextView viewCountView;

        ImageButton myButton;

        ImageView profileImageView;

    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final AListAdapter adapter = this;
        ViewHolder holder = null;


        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cell parent, false);
            TextView viewCountView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id._view_count_);
            Button likeButton = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id._like_button);
            LoadImageView profileImageView = (LoadImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.albumlist_profile_image);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.viewCountView = viewCountView;
            holder.likeButton = likeButton;
            holder.profileImageView = profileImageView;

            holder.likeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                   // how to controll TextView??????????????????
               // when click i want to change textview
                   //like holder.viewCountView.setText("clicked");
                }
            });

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        MyData data = (MyData) adapter.getItem(position);
        if (data != null) {

            holder.viewCountView.setText(String.valueOf(data.viewCount) + "views");
            //image settings 
        }
        return convertView;
    }
```

Comment: whats the problem in this viewCountView.setText("clicked");

Comment: which error you facing with this code ?

Comment: viewHolder  is cant accessed by This Scope

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cant access use local variables in this case, By the time the onClickListener is called the variables would have gone out of scope.

So instead you can set the `ViewHolder` as a tag for the button too, then you can access that in your `onClick` Handler

```
holder.likeButton.setTag(holder);
holder.likeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
       ViewHolder mH = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();

       mH.viewCountView.setText("clicked");
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried your answer, get ClassCastExeption on ' ViewHolder mH = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();`

Comment: Im not sure why this does not work, It should work. I have used it before, Your code looks otherwise fine too. Can you please fix this small Error and try? (`Button likeButton = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id._like_button)`), It should be `ImageButton likeButton = ...`

Comment: or Button on both sides, depending on how you defined it in your xml code

Comment: i'll trying again,succeed. I cant realize why didnt work.... but thanks Ahmed!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Put this code after else() part

```
        holder.likeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

               holder.viewCountView.setText("clicked");
            }
        });
```

Like this way

```
  if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cell parent, false);
        TextView viewCountView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id._view_count_);
        Button likeButton = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id._like_button);
        LoadImageView profileImageView = (LoadImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.albumlist_profile_image);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.viewCountView = viewCountView;
        holder.likeButton = likeButton;
        holder.profileImageView = profileImageView;

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    MyData data = (MyData) adapter.getItem(position);
    if (data != null) {

        holder.viewCountView.setText(String.valueOf(data.viewCount) + "views");
        //image settings 
    }


    holder.likeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

           holder.viewCountView.setText("clicked");
        }
    });
    return convertView;
```

Comment: I tried yours,got Error "Cannot refer to a non-final variable variableName inside an inner class defined in a different method"